# Not able to get scope variable value after open href in new tab or new window?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

There is any way to get scope value, while call ng-click in new tab or new window in angularjs, I did pass param with href and call ng-click and get href param and set in scope, So it's working like for single page application, But while click for open href in new tab or new window then value is not getting which was set in scope variable.

Please help me out.

Comment: any code that we can look at ?

Comment: <a data-id="{{list.id}}" data-drname="{{list.drname}}" data-locality="{{list.first_locality}}" data-specialty="{{list.speciality}}" data-sec_clinic="{{list.sec_clinic}}" data-first_clinic="{{list.first_clinic}}" ng-href="#/doctor/{{list.city}}/{{list.drname|lowercase}}" ng-click="detail(list)" class="title" >{{list.drname}} </a> this is my html 
controller
$scope.detail = function (list) {
$scope.drId =list.id;
 } and get $scope value using $routeparam.drId

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, when you open in new tab or new window, it means you have just started new app. And maybe you can't retrieve the params with $routeparam in this case.
I think you should try $location.search

Comment: thank you Nhat Hong Ly but i don't want to show param in url and location.search split query param from url.